# Spring boot app doesn't start if elasticsearch server is down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I'm using spring boot app (2.5.x), which among other thigns integrates elasticsearch. If elastic search is down, my spring boot app doesnt' start. I want the integration to work such that if elasticsearch is down, the API returns null or some sort of exception but let the app work normally for other things.

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = { "com.search.repository" })
public class ElasticSearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchConfig.class);

    /**
     * the name of the cluster for the client to connect to
     */
    @Value("#{${es.hosts}}")
    private Map<String, Integer> esHosts;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        String[] esHostWithPortArray = new String[esHosts.size()];
        int tracker = 0;
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : esHosts.entrySet()) {
            log.info("Adding the elastic search host configuration, server:{}, port:{}", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            esHostWithPortArray[tracker] = entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue();
            tracker++;
        }
        
            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder().connectedTo(esHostWithPortArray).build();
            log.info(
                    "Done creating the elasticsearch RestHighClient, no basic authentication has been provided or es.auth.basic.enabled has not been set to true");
            return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(elasticsearchClient());
    }
```

One option I have considered is to create a separate rest spring boot app which only deals with elasticsearch but wondering if there are any other option. I tried putting @lazy annotation above this configuration file but the code still tries to connect to ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1):

We probably have same issue in different setup but I'll tell what I have done to solve this startup connection exception, maybe it'll help somebody.

I am using ES 7.17.8 and spring boot 2.7.3 and spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch.

I used `@Document(createIndex = false)` in document class and with this stopped try to create index on startup. Application doesn't try to connect Elasticsearch server on startup anymore. (I handle indexing with logstash to sync relational db so I don't need in spring boot to handle that)

An then I put a try catch around `elasticsearchOperation.search` method call, with this at runtime app doesn't crash while elasticsearch server down but keep working. Any point of application running if elasticsearch server up, search method call will auto connect ES and get search result.

Comment: 'createIndex = false' worked for me too, thanks. I created the indexes manually anyway (failsafe).